# Disable aggregation for a project/task combination

Tags: scala, sbt, android-sdk-plugin

I'm looking for a way to disable test execution for the `android` project. The easiest way appeared to be aggregating all projects and to then disable aggregation for the specific project/task combination. Unfortunately this does not work with my configuration attempts shown below.

```
object Build extends sbt.Build {
    lazy val root = project.in( file( "." ) )
        .settings(
            // This setting does not have an effect,
            // all projects have their tests executed
            aggregate in ( android, test ) := false,
            publishArtifact := false
        )
        .aggregate( core, android, androidTest )

    lazy val core = project.in( file( "core" ) )
        ...

    lazy val android = project.in( file( "android" ) )
        ...
        .dependsOn( core )

    lazy val androidTest = flavorOf( android, "android-test" )
        ...
}
```

Ideally I'd prefer not to aggregate `androidTest` at all and instead forward `android/test` to `androidTest/test`, but this seems to be impossible due to cyclic references. The `flavorOf` function is part of the android-sdk-plugin for sbt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, as the last line in your build above:

```
test in android <<= test in androidTest
```

Comment: I don't like splitting up the build file, but it does actually work, so I'll live with that. `test in android <<= test in Test in androidTest`

Comment: Favor using build.sbt rather than scala

Comment: But I can't define flavors in build.sbt, can I?

Comment: You can, may have to update to latest sbt, but it works